# Get module_path from environment variable in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a few modules and the Zend Framework library in "`C:\Public\vendor`" folder. The directory looks like this:

```
vendor
 --> Module1
 --> Module2
 --> ZF2
 ----->library
 ------->Zend
```

In my PHP application, which is actually located in "`C:\Public\apps\myApplication`", I am able to get the Zend Framework path, by setting a `ZF2_PATH` environment variable in my apache's `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

However, to get the Modules to load, in `application.config.php`, I am having to mention the physical path of the module location (which might change in a production environment), ex:

```
'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
            'C:\\Public\\vendor',
        ),
```

Is there a way to set and retrieve, `module_paths` using an environment variable in apache?

Answer (score 2):

Why forget about normal PHP just when working with a Framework?

```
$modulePaths = array();
switch ($env) {
    case 'local' : $modulePaths[] = ....;
    // other cases ....
}

'module_paths' => $modulePaths,
```

Comment: Peronnaly, i use the same system for `application.config.php` than the one used for autoloading other config files : i set a `application.config.local.php`, ignored by git, which supersede the global `application.config.php` when present.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code like this to read the environment variable, set in apache and it worked..

```
'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
            getenv('CUSTOM_MODULES_PATH'),
        ),
```

Thanks for your input Sam..